# Text doesn't show when using printf in visual studio

Tags: c

I'm new to programming, so here is propably an easy problem. Im using visual studio. When i type anything and then press enter, the string doesnt show. I was trying to do hex -> decimal, but for now i deleted rest of the code.

```
int main()
{
    char liczba[5];
    printf("Write hex numb: ");
    scanf_s("%s", liczba , 1u);
    printf(" %s ",  liczba);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the same problem someone else had earlier today, this article was helpful in that case: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw#_debug-helloworldcpp

Comment: look like it's 1u (unsigned 1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked up the documentation. It notes, that in contrast to scanf for scanf_s buffer sizes need to be specified for format specifiers c, C, s and S as a second parameter following the usual one. An example:

```
char str[1024];

printf("Input text: ");
scanf_s("%s", str, 1024);
```

The documentation also states that in case of potential buffer overflow nothing is written to the buffer.

Your code works perfectly fine if you won't use "1u".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char liczba[5];
    int BUFFSIZE = 1024;
    printf("Write hex numb: ");
    scanf_s("%s", liczba , BUFFSIZE);
    printf(" %s ",  liczba);

    return 0;
}
```

I have created an integer for the buffer size, but you can also go with:

```
scanf_s("%s", liczba , 1024);
```

And size of the buffer can also be lower than 1024. For example it can be 5, but if you will input a string `"QWERTYUIOP"` your printf won't show anything.

Comment: Thank you, "1024);" doesn't work, but "BUFFSIZE);" works perfectly. (Don't know why tho)

Comment: @Aleksandra it works for me both ways. What error do you receive?